# $C$, $P$, $T$ symmetry of $O(3)$ non-linear sigma model

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, condensed-matter, spin-models, cpt-symmetry, sigma-models

Consider the $O(3)$ nonlinear sigma model with topological theta term in 1+1 D: $$\mathcal{L}=|d\textbf{n}|^{2}+\frac{i\theta}{8\pi}\textbf{n}\cdot(d\textbf{n}\times d\textbf{n}).$$
The time reversal symmetry is $$T: \textbf{n}(x,t)\to -\textbf{n}(x,-t),$$
the parity (reflection) symmetry (actually, it is $CP$ combination) is $$P^{*}: \textbf{n}(x,t)\to -\textbf{n}(-x,t),$$
and the charge conjugation symmetry is $$C: \textbf{n}(x,t)\to -\textbf{n}(x,t).$$

**It is said that the model above has time reversal and parity symmetry for any $\theta$, while it is charge conjugation symmetric only when** $\theta=0,\pi$. (references: https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.02153).

---

But it seems that

1).under time reversal symmetry $i\to -i$,then $$|d\textbf{n}(x,t)|^{2}+\frac{i\theta}{8\pi}\textbf{n}(x,t)\cdot(d\textbf{n}(x,t)\times d\textbf{n}(x,t))\to|d\textbf{n}(x,-t)|^{2}+\frac{-i\theta}{8\pi}(-)\textbf{n}(x,-t)\cdot(d\textbf{n}(x,-t)\times d\textbf{n}(x,-t)),$$
shortly,$\mathcal{L}[\textbf{n}(x,t)]\to\mathcal{L}[\textbf{n}(x,-t)]$, **Is it time reversal symmetric?** If yes, it is clearly that it has time reversal symmetry for any $\theta$.

2). for parity symmetry, $$|d\textbf{n}(x,t)|^{2}+\frac{i\theta}{8\pi}\textbf{n}(x,t)\cdot(d\textbf{n}(x,t)\times d\textbf{n}(x,t))\to|d\textbf{n}(-x,t)|^{2}+\frac{i\theta}{8\pi}(-)\textbf{n}(-x,t)\cdot(d\textbf{n}(-x,t)\times d\textbf{n}(-x,t)),$$  **Is the model has parity symmetry? The $\theta$ term now has a minus sign.** Why it is said that it has parity symmetry for any $\theta$?

3). for charge conjugation, since $i\to -i$,then $$|d\textbf{n}(x,t)|^{2}+\frac{i\theta}{8\pi}\textbf{n}(x,t)\cdot(d\textbf{n}(x,t)\times d\textbf{n}(x,t))\to|d\textbf{n}(x,t)|^{2}+\frac{-i\theta}{8\pi}(-)\textbf{n}(x,t)\cdot(d\textbf{n}(x,t)\times d\textbf{n}(x,t)),$$
shortly,$\mathcal{L}[\textbf{n}(x,t)]\to\mathcal{L}[\textbf{n}(x,t)]$, **it seems that the model has charge conjugation symmetry for any $\theta$, but why it is only a symmetry for $\theta=0,\pi$**.

Comment: I haven't looked at it in detail, but the paper is distinguishing between two types if parity operators $P$ and $P^* = CP$. I think your $P$ in the question is their $P^*$. I believe $P$ and $C$ is a symmetry only for $\theta=0,\pi$ but $P^*=CP$ is a symmetry for any $\theta$. I am not sure though, but the solution is somewhere in this distinction.

Comment: @Prahar, yes, the P above is $P^*$. But I don't understand why T is a symmetry for any $\theta$, and $C$ is a symmetry only when $\theta=0,\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

If the T map changes $\theta$ to $-\theta$, and recalling that $\theta$ is an angle --- meaning that  $\theta$ is the same   as  $\theta+2\pi$ --- only $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$ tranform into themselves.

The $\theta$ parameter is an *angle* because
$$
n=\frac 1{4\pi} \int \left\{\frac 12 \epsilon^{ijk} n^i dn^j dn^k\right\}
$$
is the *integer-valued* winding number (Brouwer degree) of the map ${\bf n}:S^2 \to S^2$, and the theta term is in an exponent where $e^{2\pi i n}=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. So the system has time reversal symmetry only when $\theta=0,pi$?

Comment: It depends on how you define the action C and T on the fields. This in turn depends on the physical interpretation of ${\bf n}$. In QCD or in condensed matter systems of fermions coupled to gauge fields, theta changes sign under T or CP

Comment: Thanks. But here it seems that $\textbf{n}\to -\textbf{n}$ under T, and also the imaginary number $i\to -i$ under T, so the $\theta$ term seems do not change sign ?

Comment: Time reversal is not usually anti-linear on the fields, nor on coupling constants, so I do not see why $i$ should go to $-i$ under $T$.  I suppose it all depends on what you are modelling here.

Answer (score 0):

I make some progress on this question:

1).under time reversal symmetry $i\to -i$,then $$|d\textbf{n}(x,t)|^{2}+\frac{i\theta}{8\pi}\textbf{n}(x,t)\cdot(d\textbf{n}(x,t)\times d\textbf{n}(x,t))\to|d\textbf{n}(x,-t)|^{2}+\frac{-i\theta}{8\pi}(-)\textbf{n}(x,-t)\cdot(d\textbf{n}(x,-t)\times d\textbf{n}(x,-t)),$$
shortly,$\mathcal{L}[\textbf{n}(x,t)]\to\mathcal{L}[\textbf{n}(x,-t)]$.

Then we need the action $S=\int dxdt\mathcal{L}[\textbf{n}(x,-t)]=\int dxdt\mathcal{L}[\textbf{n}(x,t)]$. Since $\int_{-a}^a f(-t)dt=-\int_{a}^{-a}f(\tau)d\tau$, so if we take the integral on the imaginary time from $-\beta/2$ to $\beta/2$, then we find $\int_{-\beta/2}^{\beta/2} dt\mathcal{L}[\textbf{n}(x,-t)]=\int_{-\beta/2}^{\beta/2} dxdt\mathcal{L}[\textbf{n}(x,t)]$. So the system has time reversal symmetry for any $\theta$.

3). The charge conjugation should not act on the c-number, so there is no $i\to -I$. Then $$|d\textbf{n}(x,t)|^{2}+\frac{i\theta}{8\pi}\textbf{n}(x,t)\cdot(d\textbf{n}(x,t)\times d\textbf{n}(x,t))\to|d\textbf{n}(x,t)|^{2}+\frac{i\theta}{8\pi}(-)\textbf{n}(x,t)\cdot(d\textbf{n}(x,t)\times d\textbf{n}(x,t)).$$
Since the partition function is periodic under $\theta\to \theta+2\pi$, so the system has charge conjugation when $\theta=0,\pi$.